# Using event delegation (bubbling) in web component with slot problem

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, event-bubbling, slot

I create this simple example (pure JS, not in Vue or React, etc.):

```html
<body>
  <script>
    (function () {
      class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
          super();
          const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
          const template = document.createElement('template');
          template.innerHTML = `
            <div>
              <button>
                <slot> <em>left</em> </slot>
              </button>
            </div>
          `;
          shadowRoot.append(template.content.cloneNode(true))

          shadowRoot.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            // normal event delegation stuff,
            const button = event.target.closest('button');
            if (!button) return;
            // do somthing with button
            console.log(button);
          });
        }
      }

      customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
    }());
  </script>

  <my-component id="myComponent"></my-component>
</body>
```

Currently it works well.

But, after the slot added:

```html
<my-component id="myComponent"> <span>previous</span> </my-component>
```

The event delegation code broken, because what I clicked is the Light DOM but Shadow DOM, so, I got null with `const button = event.target.closest('button');`

Any advise to use event delegation within slot?

*If there is any problom with grammar, I am Chinese :)*
*Thank you for reading*

Comment: Please create an MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also note that with slots, the slotted content *remains* in the light DOM; it's just *reflected* to the shadow DOM for **rendering purposes**. This does not change its position in the document, so any events in the light DOM never see the shadow DOM.

Comment: @connexo Thank you, MCVE added. Your comment help me confirm my thoughts, I think that I have to achieve the same goal in another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `event.composedPath()` output has all the elements the `click` Event passed.
Crossing all shadowRoot boundaries in between.

I condensed your code a *bit*...

Note: The SO snippet console is slow and verbose; check the **TOP OF** the F12 console (SO snippet could also list sandbox errors there)

```html
<script>
  customElements.define('my-component', 
   class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
       .attachShadow({mode:'open'})
       .innerHTML = `<div>
                       <button><slot>Left</slot></button>
                     </div>`;
      this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
        console.log(evt.composedPath());
      });
    }
  });
</script>

<my-component></my-component>
<my-component>Right</my-component>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, evt.composedPath() worked. I just need find the right target in composedPath array.